# Github Action with Pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, github-actions

I am getting error that pytest command not found. Below is my action file. I am using pipfile.lock to install dependencies.

```
name: Python application

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: 3.7
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pipenv
        pipenv install --dev
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you never actually installed pytest.

Try adding a *pip install* to your pytest section:

```
- name: Test with pytest
  run: |
    pip install pytest
    pytest
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not learning from how pytest is doing itself? Most python projects use tox as an orchestrator for running tests in various environments, including pytest.

This is an important aspect because you do not want to build-up too much code inside your github actions which are useless for local testing. tox works with both.

How to orchestrate tox, look at https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml